# Tiny and cheap data storage on Azure

Tags: database, azure, storage

I need to store permanently some data. I don't want to use SQL database because of pricing (Azure) and the amount of data. I need to store only few configuration objects (having no more than 10 properties). New data will be added very rarely (let's say few objects in a month). Do anybody know how can I store that little amount of data paying as little as possible using Azure platform?

Comment: Have a look at [Table Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/tables/)

Comment: All storage options, and pricing, are fully documented. I would start there. Pricing questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use Azure Storage Tables, its dirt cheap, allows to store key value pair. Its fairly easy to implement as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-overview

Comment: Thanks. It looks quite good, but I see that there are also blobs. What do you think will be better solution?

Comment: blobs dont allow to store key-value pair (at least not natively). table storage looks like a better option